# Why is this (Django) 'filter' function not working?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-filter, django-pagination

I need help to figure out why the filtering doesn't work. It worked until I decided to add pagination using Django [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/#the-paginator-class) and code comes from [here](https://nemecek.be/blog/105/how-to-use-elided-pagination-in-django-and-solve-too-many-pages-problem).) I tested the query results in Django shell (following the steps in the docs ) and tweaked the code. The pagination itself displays, but instead of 5 items on each page (as specified in the line `paginator = Paginator(gem_list, 5)`, all the items are displayed--and the same on every page. So I'm baffled as to whether the problem is with the `filter` part, or with the template.

```
#views.py

def gem_list(request):
   # gem_list = Rhyme.objects.filter(is_gem=True)
    rhyme_list = Rhyme.objects.all()
    objects= list(rhyme_list)     #converting the queryset to a list
    gem_list = objects.filter(is_gem=True)
    paginator = Paginator(gem_list, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1) 
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    page_range = paginator.get_elided_page_range(number=page) 
    
    try:
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page_obj = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page_obj = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'page_obj': page_obj,
        'gem_list' : gem_list,
        'paginator' : paginator,
        'page' : page,    
        }
    return render(request, 'rhymes/gem_list.html', context)

#template:
<div class="container">

{% for gem in gem_list %}

    <p class="rhyme_list"> <a href="{{ gem.get_absolute_url }}">{{gem}}</a></p>

{% endfor %}


<ul class="pagination justify-content-center flex-wrap mt-3 mb-4">
  {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">First</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
  {% else %}
      <li class="disabled page-item"><span class="page-link">Previous</span></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% for i in page_range|default_if_none:page_obj.paginator.get_elided_page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == i %}
          <li class="active page-item"><span class="page-link">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>
          </li>
      {% else %}
          {% if i == page_obj.paginator.ELLIPSIS %}
              <li class="page-item"><span class="page-link">{{ i }}</span></li>
          {% else %}
              <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a></li> 
  {% else %}
      <li class="disabled page-item"><span class="page-link">&raquo;</span></li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>


    #models.py
    class Rhyme(models.Model):
        rhyme = models.TextField(max_length=120)
        create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        is_gem = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        contributor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="contributor", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "rhymes"

        def __str__(self):
            return self.rhyme

        @property
        def num_rhymes(self):
            return Rhyme.objects.all.count()

        @property
        def contributor_rhyme_count(self):
            return Rhyme.objects.filter(rhymes=self).count()

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('rhyme_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return "/rhymes/{}/".format(self.pk)

        # Metadata
        class Meta:
            ordering = ['rhyme']
```

Comment: ```objects= list(rhyme_list)  
gem_list = objects.filter(is_gem=True)```
Can you filter after you've converted to list?

Comment: @DarrenG I think your question is about whether the filtering process should take place prior to the conversion to list. I have played with that with the filtering first (` gem_list = Rhyme.objects.filter(is_gem=True)   objects= list(gem_list)`), but that seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to display the page objects (`page_obj`) instead of the full gem_list:

```
{% for gem in page_obj %}

    <p class="rhyme_list"> <a href="{{ gem.get_absolute_url }}">{{gem}}</a></p>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That worked! I could swear I tried `page_obj` once, but with so many moving parts, any one part could have thrown me off. Thanks!